# DAO.Recordset, unable to MoveNext in table object

Tags: vba, ms-access, dao, recordset

Goal:  I am writing a loop to go through a table, row by row, evaluate if fields match eachother, then move to the next record (row) and re-evaluate.  I eventually want to build a ever-growing string out of it, but for now I cannot get the Code to go to the next loop.  The value(s) show that the code only evaluates the first record, and repeats itself.

I've tried moving the line 'ExDif.MoveNext' into/out of the loop, before/after the End If, no change.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Sub Export_Library_Compare_Process()

'Identify the variables
Dim Tang As DAO.Database
Dim ExDif As DAO.Recordset
Dim Field01a As DAO.Field
Dim Field01b As DAO.Field
Dim ID As DAO.Field

'Set the database and recordsets to database and tables
Set Tang = CurrentDb
Set ExDif = Tang.OpenRecordset("Staging_LOG_ExportDifferences")
Set Field01a = ExDif.Fields("a_Client Name")
Set Field01b = ExDif.Fields("b_Client Name")
Set ID = ExDif.Fields("ID")

'Start a series to look to see what matches
Do While Not ExDif.EOF

    'Move to first row in table
    ExDif.MoveFirst

    'Field 01 - Client Name
    If Field01a.Value <> Field01a.Value Then
        MsgBox "Client Name does not match"
    Else: MsgBox "Client Name matches"

    'Move to next record (row) in table
    ExDif.MoveNext

    'End the Else - If
    End If

'End Loop
Loop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several problems.

> ```
> Set ExDif = Tang.OpenRecordset("Staging_LOG_ExportDifferences")
> Set Field01a = ExDif.Fields("a_Client Name")
> Set Field01b = ExDif.Fields("b_Client Name")
> Set ID = ExDif.Fields("ID")
> ```

This code starts reading the recordset before it's known that there are records. If the recordset is empty (i.e. recordset is both `BOF` and `EOF`), these subsequent assignments will fail with an error. These assignments should be inside the record-reader loop.

> ```
> ExDif.MoveFirst
> ```

You're *already* on the first record; moving the cursor back to the first record unconditionally, at each iteration, is why your loop is stuck on the first record. Remove this line.

> ```
> If Field01a.Value <> Field01a.Value Then
> ```

This expression will always evaluate to `False`, it's a heuristically constant expression, likely a typo. Was it meant to compare `Field01a` with `Field01b`?

> ```
> Else: MsgBox "Client Name matches"
>
> 'Move to next record (row) in table
> ExDif.MoveNext
>
> 'End the Else - If
> End If
> ```

This indentation is very misleading and very, very error-prone. Consider:

```
Else
    MsgBox "Client Name matches"
    ExDif.MoveNext
End If
```

Now, `.MoveNext` being conditional (somewhat - see previous point about the condition expression), is a problem: **no matter what happens in the loop body**, you want to be on the next record when you're done. So `.MoveNext` should never be conditional.

---

This should fix it:

```
Set exportDiffs = Tang.OpenRecordset("Staging_LOG_ExportDifferences")
Do Until exportDiffs.EOF

    Dim clientNameA As String
    clientNameA = exportDiffs.Fields("a_Client Name").Value

    Dim clientNameB As String
    clientNameB = exportDiffs.Fields("b_Client Name").Value

    If clientNameA <> clientNameB Then
        'client name mismatch
        GoTo Skip
    End If

    Dim id As Long
    id = exportDiffs.Fields("ID").Value

    ' do stuff...

Skip:
    exportDiffs.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: Thanks @Mathieu, this cleared up some other issues I was having

Answer (score 0):

I have some unusual security restrictions at my job, which I'm blaming on this not working.  But I looked at some Access Programming boards, and found this post [https://access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=171138] which let me know I can make a loop using either "Do While" or "Do Until".  When I tried switching the loop style to "Do Until" it worked fine.

Do Until ExDif.EOF

Comment: At every iteration, you're invoking `.MoveFirst` unconditionally, then `.MoveNext` only when `Field01a.Value <> Field01a.Value` ...a condition that can only ever be `False` - therefore, the loop is infinitely processing the first record (side note, `Else:` should be `Else` with the rest of the block properly indented). Also you begin reading the recordset before you know whether it contains any records. The problem can't possibly be with `Do While Not` vs `Do Until`, which are exactly equivalent - only, `Do Until` avoids the negative phrasing and should thus be preferred.

Comment: There shouldn't be any condition attached to `.MoveNext`. Whatever happens in the loop body, you want that to be *for every record*, and you want to be on the next record when you hit that `Loop` keyword and jump back up to re-evaluate whether you have any more records to process.